# Cron to check dates in large MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have a database that around 8 fields in various tables are dates and these need to be checked everyday for if they are about to or have already expired.

I want to use a CRON Job to achieve this, but baring in mind that the database will eventually have 50,000 rows possibly more. Running a script that checks all of the dates would most likely time out.

I was thinking of segmenting the search script into chunks. So it will run for a few thousand rows then stop. Then five minutes later pick up from where it left of, by querying a field in the database that stores where it last finished. And once it has iterated through all rows stop.

But I don't know if this is wise or even possible for a script to set itself to run again in 5 minutes.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: But... It's a database! Why would you check row-by-row? You could write a query that returns all the expired rows. Maybe add an index to the date columns if it's a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't have to run over the complete table. You could just run a query for that right?

```
SELECT something FROM tbl_name WHERE NOW() >= date_col;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [mysql event scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/events.html) to do that.
This code will create an event that will automatically execute once a day to delete outdated records from your table:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE EVENT myevent
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 DAY
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO BEGIN
 DELETE FROM mytable WHERE col1<NOW();
 DELETE FROM mytable WHERE col2<NOW();
 DELETE FROM mytable WHERE col3<NOW();
 DELETE FROM mytable WHERE col4<NOW();
 DELETE FROM mytable WHERE col5<NOW();
 DELETE FROM mytable WHERE col6<NOW();
 DELETE FROM mytable WHERE col7<NOW();
 DELETE FROM mytable WHERE col8<NOW();
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Documentation:
[CREATE EVENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-event.html)
[BEGIN...END](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/begin-end.html)